# Time complexity to construct a Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, hashtable, inorder

What can be the time complexity to construct a Binary tree from given **in-order** and **level-order** traversals, if we are using **hash-table for lookup**?

I was going through [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-inorder-level-order-traversals/)

But, I am not getting how to find time complexity for this using hash look up?

Comment: What have you found so far?

Comment: I was referring this link . i think it can be done in O(N^2) http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-inorder-level-order-traversals/